# Len(Columns(lastColumn + ":" + c))

Tags: vba, excel

I have been messing around with this line of code for some time already and I still can't seem to make it run.

The part of the code that I have problem with is this:

```
TempW = Len(Columns(lastColumn + ":" + c))
```

I'm trying to get the length of the text that is located inside a peculiar cell based on the column and join all the lengths together into a string.

*Example, 7,8,2,13,40*.

I want the output to be like this is because I want to use it as an array like this `CWSize = Array(CWStore)`.

Number of Columns is not constant.

Here is my code:

```
Sub testColumnLen()

    Dim CWArray As Variant, CWSize As String, TempW As Long, c As Integer, lastColumn As Long
    Dim CWStore As String

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    c = 1
    TempW = Len(Columns(lastColumn + ":" + c))
    c = 2
    CWStore = TempW
    Do While c < lastColumn
        TempW = Len(Columns(lastColumn + ":" + c))
        CWStore = CWStore + "," + TempW
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    CWSize = Array(CWStore)
    CWArray = CWSize
    Debug.Print CWArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Columns() returns a number. Len on a numeric value would lead to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code:

```
Sub testColumnLen()

    Dim CWSize As Variant, TempW As Long, c As Integer, lastColumn As Long
    Dim CWStore As String, i As Long

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    c = 1
    Do While c <= lastColumn
        TempW = Len(Cells(1, c))
        If CWStore = "" Then
            CWStore = TempW
        Else
            CWStore = CWStore & "," & TempW
        End If
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    Debug.Print CWStore    '---> this will give you comma separated values

    CWSize = Split(CWStore, ",")
    For i = LBound(CWSize) To UBound(CWSize)
        Debug.Print CWSize(i)    '---> this will give you individual lengths of cell
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I finally can continue my project :D

Comment: @EdwardPhang - Great! All the best for for your project.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub testColumnLen()
    Dim CWArray As Variant
    Dim CWStore As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            CWStore = CWStore & Len(cell) & " "
        Next cell

    End With
    CWArray = Split(Left(CWStore, Len(CWStore) - 1))
End Sub
```

or maybe you need the final array be set as

`CWArray = Array(Left(CWStore, Len(CWStore) - 1))`

Comment: Thank you for replying but how to check if the value is stored?

Comment: I have run the code that you have provided but I can't seem to be able to display its content by using this code
`CWArray = Array(Left(CWStore, Len(CWStore) - 1))
    For i = LBound(CWArray) To UBound(CWArray)
    Msg = Msg & CWArray(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i
    MsgBox "the values of my dynamic array are: " & vbNewLine & Msg
`

Comment: that listing code works perfectly in my test. use VBA IDE and step through the code with F8 querying variables content in the `Immediate Window` and/or in the `Locals Window`  to see what are you getting step by step. For instance you could put a breakpoint at the `CWArray = Split(Left(CWStore, Len(CWStore) - 1))` statement and once the code reaches it watch in the `Locals Window` what is there in `CWStore`. then press F8 once and watch in the `Locals Window` what is there in `CWArray`.

Comment: Ahhh, Thank you so much I now understand it already :D, But I do need it to separated each length with a comma. However I really want to say Thank you so much for helping me. :D

Comment: You are welcome but I doubt I really helped you. I answered giving solution of OP's question which was specifically about the _"part of the code that I have problem with"_. I also adjusted the variables dimensioning  and showed you how to obtain an array using Split() function. I shiwed you how to obtain two different arrays.  An array doesn't mind nor have any "separator" (be it a comma or a space or whatever). Finally I answered first. Still you didn't accept my answer as the solution. You see why I doubt I really helped you.